# How is this basic 3D animation template created?

Tags: after-effects, animation, 3d, blender

I found this "3D Character Template" which can be used in after effects:

https://videohive.net/item/martin-3d-character-man-presentermanager-product-promotion/6886216?s_rank=52

How can I make these 3D animated characters myself? Because I'd hate to use templates, it makes the work unprofessional so I want to learn to create these myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question in your tags: use **Animation** in a **3D** package like **Blender**.

But TBH your question is too broad to be answerable. To tell you how to make those 3D characters yourself we'd have to explain modelling, rigging, skinning lighting and rendering, not to mention the principles of animation. To give even a basic explanation of any one of those topics would be way beyond the scope of a Stack Exchange anser.

It's complex and takes a good while to master. If you want to do 3D animation, get a copy of Blender and start watching tutorials, reading books and practising. It's like any other skill set that has to be learned. There is no short cut... apart from buying templates.

Comment: Sounds like it takes more than a year, The way it looked so simple I thought it'd be easy, guess I was wrong :d

Comment: When I taught animation it took about a semester to get the students doing basic walk cycles, with one class per week.